# What's causing this error in my mutation observer using script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, mutation-observers

The **original question asked has been answered**. In addition, **someone outside of Stackoverflow has provided a full solution to what I was trying to achieve** with my script, which I have added as an answer to my question. The script itself and a summary of the specific problem it solves is detailed in my own answer.

*Original Question:*

I'm not a programmer, unfortunately, so my experience is very limited.

My browser overwrites a correct `img` `src` with an incorrect `src` a couple of seconds after it starts.

My script's intended function is a work-around to immediately replace the broken `src` with the correct `src` again, at the time my browser overwrites the correct `src`.

```
function getElementsBySrc(srcValue) {
  var nodes = [];
  var e = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

  for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    if (e[i].hasAttribute('src') && e[i].getAttribute('src') == srcValue) {
      nodes.push(e[i]);
    }
  }

  return nodes;
}

function initMod(){
    if(!document.querySelector("#browser")){
        setTimeout(initMod, 1000);
        return;
    }

var targetNode = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var config = { attributes: true, childList: false, subtree: false, characterData: false };

var callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    for(var mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.type == 'attributes') {

            console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');

            var n = getElementsBySrc('https://hyperspace.marquiskurt.net/icons/favicon-32x32.png');
            for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
                n[i].setAttribute('src', 'chrome://favicon/https://hyperspace.marquiskurt.net/app/');
            }

        }
    }
};

var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

observer.observe(targetNode, config);

}
initMod();
```

The script is loaded directly as my browser starts. My Chrome Devtools Console gives the error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('img');` is not a NODE, it is a `HTMLcollection` of nodes

Comment: by the way, running `observer.observe(targetNode, config);

observer.disconnect();` like that will ensure the observer never runs anyway :p

Comment: also worth mentioning `img.getAttribute('src')` isn't always the same as `img.src` - are you sure you know which one is relevant to your requirements?

Comment: Thank you. I see, that explains some issues with the script. I'm not a programmer so there's definitely more than one thing wrong with the script. And yes, I am sure that I need `img.getAttribute('src')` not `img.src`.

Comment: The script does work without mutation observer, however it relies on a delay, which is not ideal, because it means that I'll actually see a visual change of the `src` being broken and then fixed again. I guess I still need to wait for someone who's kind enough to show me how to fix the main issue in my script. (I also updated the script to remove `observer.disconnect();`.

Comment: so, if the img src is set using `//hyperspace.marquiskurt.net/icons/favicon-32x32.png` rather than `https://hyperspace.marquiskurt.net/icons/favicon-32x32.png` you DONT want that one changed?

Comment: I don't totally understand your question so I'll just explain what the script's intended function is. The original and correct src is `chrome://favicon/https://hyperspace.marquiskurt.net/app/`, it gets changed into the broken src `https://hyperspace.marquiskurt.net/icons/favicon-32x32.png`. The script is supposed to detect that change and immediately change it back to `chrome://favicon/https://hyperspace.marquiskurt.net/app/`.

Comment: fair enough, in this case it doesn't make a difference then - if you want to see what I mean, https://jsfiddle.net/guzsk84m/1/ ... but it's not important - anyway, posted an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as `document.getElementsByTagName('img');` returns a *list* of elements, not a node, you can't use `targetNode` (because it isn't a node)

Here I'm using `document.querySelectorAll` instead, same result, but it has a forEach method that I use to create the mutation observers for each IMG

```
function initMod() {
    if(!document.querySelector("#browser")){
        setTimeout(initMod, 1000);
        return;
    }

    const callback = (mutationsList, observer) => {
        for(let mutation of mutationsList) {
            if (mutation.type == 'attributes') {
                console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
                const n = getElementsBySrc('https://hyperspace.marquiskurt.net/icons/favicon-32x32.png');
                for (let e of n) {
                    e.setAttribute('src', 'chrome://favicon/https://hyperspace.marquiskurt.net/app/');
                }
            }
        }
    };
    const config = { attributes: true, childList: false, subtree: false, characterData: false };
    document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(targetNode => {
        const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
        observer.observe(targetNode, config);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tested the script. That did fix the error given in the console. It seems that the script still does not do what it's intended to do though, as the broken src does not get replaced. I also reduced the initMod delay to 200, and it seems to still not be working. Which, I'm slightly dumbstruck about.

Comment: Is it possible that the script is detecting other changes in img attributes and failing to find a `src` set as `https://hyperspace.marquiskurt.net/icons/favicon-32x32.png`, and then stopping there?

Comment: Console logging will help you find what's going on

Answer (score 0):

Someone very kindly provided a solution that achieved exactly what I was trying to do.

```
const selector = "#panels img[src='https://hyperspace.marquiskurt.net/icons/favicon-32x32.png']";
function fixImages() {
    const maybeBadImage = document.querySelector(selector);
    if(maybeBadImage){
        maybeBadImage.src = "chrome://favicon/https://hyperspace.marquiskurt.net/app/";
    }
}
const observer = new MutationObserver(fixImages);
function initMod() {
    if(!document.querySelector(selector)){
        setTimeout(initMod, 0);
        return;
    }
    observer.observe(document.querySelector(selector), { attributes: true });
    fixImages();
}
initMod();
```

With `setTimeout` set to 0, the broken `src` is immediately corrected without any visual change that the user can see. This script can be modified for use if anyone else is having the issue where the web browser Vivaldi incorrectly modifies the `src` for the favicon of a specific user-added web panel.